# d3.js force piechart nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

I am interested in making this force-piechart hybrid. I've tried merging these two charts together - to create a placeholder for the pie chart module to become exposed.

//pie chart
http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/10111/

//Force chart
http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/10110/

//merged chart attempt1
http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/10114/

//merged chart attempt 2 - LATEST
http://jsfiddle.net/k0pn3x5o/3/

```
  var datajson = {
    "name": "parentnode",
    "children": [{
      "name": "A",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Cherry",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "Apple",
        "size": 3812
      }, {
        "name": "Banana",
        "size": 6714
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "B",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Strawberry",
        "size": 3938
      }, {
        "name": "Apricot",
        "size": 3812
      }]
    }]
  };
```

Comment: With the force nodes -- do I need to re-create a set of nodes as g elements with circles nested inside -- then hook into the parent g element nodes as placeholders? -- http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/10116/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/10117/  -- I've tried nesting the nodes as g elements - but now the chart is breaking up -

Answer (score 5):

You just need to use the correct node elements and update them correctly.

Use a `g` for the node then put whatever you want inside.

```
 node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr('transform', d => ("translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"))
    //Insert pie chart here.
```

Inside the tick function you then only need to update the outer `g` position to have it layout correctly.

```
node.attr('transform', d => ("translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k0pn3x5o/

Comment: The pie charts are non-dragable objects - is there a way of keeping that UX feature on the other dots? http://jsfiddle.net/k0pn3x5o/1/  @Andrew

Comment: Is it possible to generate the pie chart - at the time the circles are appended - so hook into the data from the node at that point? @Andrew -- http://jsfiddle.net/k0pn3x5o/3/

Comment: There is a bounty out to make the chart more like the design - fix the colors/link lengths -- @Andrew -- http://jsfiddle.net/k0pn3x5o/3/

Comment: I got another chart @Andrew that could do with some stability -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415966/d3-js-chemical-tube-bar-chart   http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1855/